# What technology is required for sites like www.trump.com and www.hyundaiusa.com?

Tags: flash

I want to learn how to develop sites like www.hyundaiusa.com and www.trump.com. Which technologies do I need to learn?, or is there a web software or studio needed for such flashy sites? Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: For http://trump.com/, it's lots of slow Flash. For http://hyundiusa.com/, it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trump.com is made with flash, very poorly done as i found 5 bugs in it the whole 2 minutes i had a browse.

the software you are wanting to get familiar with is adobe flash, the code language is actionScript. there are several flavours to go about achieving animation online.Flex is an alternative but completly different is "silverlight" check the Xbox website their animations are would be compiled through that.

I advise if you want to get involved in web programming start with php or C++, flash has abilities to animate and what not but if you can get your head around the terminolgies and structures of these other languages i had just mentioned well you will be better off.